# NzTree in NzDropdown does not render correctly

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I needed to put a tree within a dropdown to act as a filter in a table. When you mark the checkboxes of the tree elements, close the menu and reopen it, the tree doesn't render.

[image: tree filter]

I've made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-ivy-tn6vgm) with minimal code.

I have found the answer and will post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is related with an [Angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24041) about conflicting animations of various components. Is present across the NgZorro library as well as others, and manifests when you combine components that have animations.

[The solution](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/4576#issuecomment-567340416) I found (given by a maintainer of NgZorro) is to use *nzNoAnimation* to disable animation on one component in order to avoid the conflict. The [NgZorro docs](https://ng.ant.design/docs/animations/en) show how to work with the directive.

I applied the directive to the tree, because I wanted to keep the menu animation and now works correctly. The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-ivy-tn6vgm) shows the working state.